# Postgres query including time range

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that pulls part of the data that I need for tracking. What I need to add is either a column that includes the date or the ability to query the table for a date range. I would prefer the column if possible. I am using psql 8.3.3.

Here is the current query:

```
select count(mailing.mailing_id) as mailing_count, department.name as org 
from mailing, department 
where mailing.department_id = department.department_id 
group by department.name;
```

This returns the following information:

```
mailing_count  |                   org                   
---------------+-----------------------------------------
             2 | org1 name
             8 | org2 name
            22 | org3 name
            21 | org4 name
            39 | org5 name
```

The table that I am querying has 3 columns that have date in a timestamp format which are `target_launch_date`, `created_time` and `modified_time`.

When I try to add the date range to the query I get an error:

**Query:**

```
select count(mailing.mailing_id) as mailing_count, department.name as org 
from mailing, department 
where mailing.department_id = department.department_id 
group by department.name,
WHERE (target_launch_date)>= 2016-09-01 AND < 2016-09-05;
```

**Error:**

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" LINE 1:
>   ...department.department_id group by department.name,WHERE(targ...

I've tried moving the location of the date range in the string and a variety of other changes, but cannot achieve what I am looking for.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a query that would do what you need:

```
SELECT 
  count(m.mailing_id) as mailing_count, 
  d.name as org 
FROM mailing m
JOIN department d USING( department_id )
WHERE 
  m.target_launch_date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-05'
GROUP BY 2
```

Since your `target_launch_date` is of type `timestamp` you can safely do `<= '2016-09-05'` which will actually convert to `2016-09-05 00:00:00.00000` giving you all the dates that are before start of that day or exactly `2016-09-05 00:00:00.00000`

Couple of additional notes:

- Use aliases for table names to shorten the code, eg. `mailing  m`
- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax to connect data from related tables
- Apply your `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY` to exclude rows that don't match it
- Use `BETWEEN` operator to handle `date >= X AND date <= Y` case
- You can use `USING` instead of `ON` in JOIN syntax when joined column names are the same
- You can use column numbers in `GROUP BY` which point to position of a column in your select

To gain more insight on the matter of how processing of a `SELECT` statement behaves in steps look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html).

**Edit**

Approach using `BETWEEN` operator would account `2015-09-05 00:00:00.00000` to the resultset. If this timestamp should be discarded change `BETWEEN x AND y` to either of those two:

- `(...) BETWEEN x AND y::timestamp - INTERVAL '1 microsecond'`
- `(...) >= x AND (...) < y`

Comment: The original question is using a range of the form `date >= X and date < Y` so the `BETWEEN` operator isn't quite appropriate in this case.

Comment: I think it would be < '2016/09/05' otherwise it might select items from '2016/09/05' too, no? IMHO between operator should not be used for ranges that may have time component (what is the upper limit?).

Comment: No they wouldn't be discarded. Where does it says that they would?

Comment: What happens when the timestamp also includes time? e.g., "2020-03-01 00:13:01", and we also would like to select time range not just date?

Comment: You need to include specific timestamps, or if the date and time are not related, then you will need to use two separate conditions and use conjunction.

Comment: Ok, this worked for me:  ``select whatever_column FROM  some_table WHERE time_column > '2020-03-01 00:00:01'::TIMESTAMP AND time_column < '2020-03-01 01:13:01'::TIMESTAMP``

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you need to supply the column name on second part of where too and you would have a single where:

```
select count(mailing.mailing_id) as mailing_count, department.name as org 
  from mailing 
  inner join department on mailing.department_id = department.department_id 
  where target_launch_date >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'
    AND target_launch_date < '2016-09-05 00:00:00'
  group by department.name;
```

EDIT: This part is just for Kamil G. showing clearly that between should NOT be used:

```
create table sample (id int, d timestamp);

insert into sample (id, d) 
values 
(1, '2016/09/01'),
(2, '2016/09/02'),
(3, '2016/09/03'),
(4, '2016/09/04'),
(5, '2016/09/05'),
(6, '2016/09/05 00:00:00'),
(7, '2016/09/05 00:00:01'),
(8, '2016/09/06');

select * from sample where d between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-05';
```

Result:

```
1;"2016-09-01 00:00:00"
2;"2016-09-02 00:00:00"
3;"2016-09-03 00:00:00"
4;"2016-09-04 00:00:00"
5;"2016-09-05 00:00:00"
6;"2016-09-05 00:00:00"
```

BTW if you wouldn't believe without seeing explain, then here it is:

> Filter: ((d >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND
>   (d <= '2016-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))

Comment: Strangely nobody says anything about a specific time range, just data and 00:00:00, it's unbelievable that something like ``between "2019-09-11 00:12:01" and "2019-09-11 20:12:01"`` wouldn't exist!

Comment: @quanta, I am sorry I don't understand what you mean. If you are saying you need to have time part too in a range query, then you shouldn't use BETWEEN in the first place. BETWEEN implicitly means dtCol >= startVal AND dtCol <= endVal. When time is included, there is no way to specify the endVal. You should change your query to read dtCol >= startVal AND dtCol < endVal where endVal is the minimum value that you want to exclude (ie: May 2020 would be 2020-05-01 AND 2020-06-01). Probably you didn't understand the samples above showing why BETWEEN should NOT be used.

Comment: I understood your point, I was just referring to the fact that **time range** wasn't covered in any of the answers, here and in most threads. I needed the time part and found this thread based on the title that said **time range** but couldn't find a straight-forward answer. I took bits and pieces and found this to be working for me: ``select whatever_column FROM  some_table WHERE time_column > '2020-03-01 00:00:01'::TIMESTAMP AND time_column < '2020-03-01 01:13:01'::TIMESTAMP``

Comment: @quanta, there is a straight-forward answer above. What you have written is already there in the code at top.

Comment: I didn't see any specific example with time, all examples had only date in their query and in some case ``00:00:00.00000``, a straightforward example with times other than ``00:00:00.00000`` would be very helpful for an absolute newbie though. But thanks.